# Place road card in between the Treasure cards

Tags: saboteur-2, saboteur

If I have a continuous road to a Treasure Card, and that treasure card is not the Gold Card, can I place a new road card right in between the Treasure Cards and to flip the next Treasure Card, or do I have to build a new road starting from begining ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like gems, coal lumps due not bock the road. The path to the treasure may pass through a card with a coal lump.

If they wanted the path to be blocked, they would have used something like the existing 4-way dead-end.

[image: 4-way dead end]

Based on experience, starting from the original ladder would not be feasible.

Comment: So basically after flipping a Treasure Card and finding that is not the gold, the next guy can put just one road card ( if it maches the road ) and flip the next card, right ?

Comment: Yes. The path to the treasure may pass through a card with a coal lump.

Comment: otherwise there would be no point to having a path on the gold and coal cards.